# Not able to swizzle NSOutputStream's write:MaxLength:

Tags: ios, swizzling, nsoutputstream

I have a requirement of writing a custom data, before the actual write of NSOutputStream happens.

To make swizzling code execute, i have created a category NSOutputStream(SwizzleWrite), which contains the following:

```
SEL originalSelector = @selector(write:maxLength:);
SEL swizzledSelector = @selector(swizzledWrite:maxLength:);

Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod([NSOutputStream class], originalSelector);
Method swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod([self class], swizzledSelector);

method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
```

I then create Inout & Output stream:
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToCFHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, hostRef, 80, &readStream, &writeStream);

```
inputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSInputStream *)readStream;
outputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
[inputStream setDelegate:self];
[outputStream setDelegate:self];
[inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[inputStream open];
[outputStream open];
```

But now when the control reaches handleEvent: delegate, specifically on: *[outputStream write:rawstring maxLength:sizeof(rawstring)];*, i do not get it on swizzledWrite:maxLength:

What am i doing wrong here?

PS: I have read that swizzling Apple methods is not Appstore-friendly, but i have also read cases where they are accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you feel that swizzling is the best option here? Sounds to me like a subclass would be much better. There are some tricky parts about subclassing a stream but take a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSOutputStream_Class/index.html)

If you are determined to make swizzling work, have you set breakpoints and made sure that your swizzling selectors are not nil? Might happen if you get the signatures a bit wrong

Comment: Oh maybe I read your question wrong. Is the problem that handleEvent is not called on your swizzled function?

Comment: Hey Yaser, i get valid references for both original and to-be-swizzled-with selectors. I am not swizzling handleEvent: It is working the way it should be. Problem is when i get NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable i call write:maxLength, ideally i should get a call on the swizzled selector but i dont.

Comment: Also, i don't know if swizzling is the best option here but subclassing won't help as the code i am working on is exposed as a framework.

Comment: Okay, so I understood you correct. Are you sure you are running the swizzling code only once?

Comment: I do #import "NSOutputStream+SwizzleWrite.h" in AppDelegate, that calls the 'load' method of this class. I have a breakpoint at the load method. I get the control only once.